# jQuery / JS display large set of elements: show() vs append()

Tags: jquery, performance, optimization, append, show

```
<div class="snippet">
    <p> 1</p>
    //dozens of elements here
</div>

<div class="snippet">
    <p> 2</p>
    //dozens of elements here
</div>

....

<div class="snippet">
    <p> ~200</p>
    //dozens of elements here
</div>
```

Between 100 and 200 divs like this are created in steps i.e one by one (with delay)

and displayed at ONCE in the end. I see two options:

1. Create a hidden div(container) -> then at each step append a div(snippet) -> do div(container).show() ONCE.
2. Store the divs(snippet) without putting them in the DOM, at the end wrap them into a div(container) and append it.

What are the pros/cons of both and is there a better way? The code will run on low-power devices.

I know about the cost of the touching the DOM. I hope this question is helpfull in future.

Comment: This theorical question is interesting. I won't be able to answer, but I'll follow. I think you should complete the question on how you manage the "delays". Are they concurring setTimeouts? Are they ajax calls? And what does contain all those p? Images and videos or just a couple text lines? ;)

Comment: I don't know what kind of data your page will show and what you have in mind with this. But from a users point of view I would append each snippet as soon as it's available. Otherwise it might take too long for a user until anything is displayed at all (possibly thinking something is wrong and hitting F5).

Comment: Thank you! I created a jsperf performance test case:

https://jsperf.com/dom-large-set-of-elements-show-vs-append
https://jsperf.com/dom-large-set-append-vs-show/2


A div containing 200 div each with a dozen children sitting hidd
en in the DOM is better to show than to append the exact same div from outside the dom.

Please run the test to have more coverage.